# Expression for conditional probability with many variables

Tags: regression, probability, bayesian

Say I'm interested in predicting the random variable $Y$, and I have multiple data sets for random variables $A,B,C,D,E,F,G$ that $Y$ may depend on.

It seems the correct expression would be 
$$P(Y|A,B,C,D,E,F,G),$$ which gets somewhat complex quickly if I don't want to assume independence of $A,B,C,D,E,F,G$

Is there a robust way in which I can model the conditional probability separately, i.e.
$$P(Y|A)$$
$$P(Y|B)$$
$$...$$
and then combine the results to predict $P(Y)$?

For example, if we rewrite it using Bayes theorem and drop the marginal probability term, we get:
$$P(Y|A,B,C,D,E,F,G) \propto P(A,B,C,D,E,F,G|Y)P(Y)$$
where we only need to assume conditional independence given Y, but not independence of the variables.

Are there other approahces I can take?

Comment: By 'model the conditional probability separately' I assume you mean assuming independence? From your question it at first sounded like that is something you want to avoid.

Comment: thanks @Rickyfox. sorry my wording may have been awkward, I've added an example to make it clearer